# Convert XML to JSON and force it to arrays

Tags: php, json, xml

How can I make this: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm but in PHP?

I mean, now my JSON is with only {} brackets. I need [] brackets, when there are specific xml tags

I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <name>xfvxvxffxv</name>
    <fullpaths>
        <name>main_table</name>
        <fullpaths>
            <name>banutoor</name>
            <fullpaths>
                <name>agu12</name>
                <size>3</size>
            </fullpaths>
            <fullpaths>
                <name>agu88</name>
                <size>3</size>
            </fullpaths>
            <fullpaths>
                <name>igu77</name>
                <size>67</size>
            </fullpaths>
            <fullpaths>
                <name>igu</name>
                <size>1288</size>
            </fullpaths>
        </fullpaths>
    </fullpaths>
</root>
```

and this is how at the moment I made it:

```
$xmlP = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $xmlP));
$simple = simplexml_load_string($xmlP);
$json = json_encode($simple);
```

and where it is `<fullpaths>` I need to be

```
"name": "xfvxvxffxv",
   "fullpaths": [ ......
```

in the JSON.

Now it is:

```
"name": "xfvxvxffxv",
    "fullpaths": {
```

Comment: You wan't an array instead of an object? What is your problem with it? Cause you can still iterate through the values..?

Comment: Hi Darren, I need to generate file flpths.json. And then in case certain conditions are met, I need to send a "flag 1" to a remote API, to inform the API about that, the file flpths.json is with new content. I dont know what is over there on the remote API.

Comment: Actually I found this: http://outlandish.com/blog/xml-to-json/ and it is enough for me. Thanks to wogsland and Darren!